# Selecting Radio Buttons only in single div

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Actually I'm doing tasks from http://demo.seleniumeasy.com/basic-radiobutton-demo.html - Group Radio Buttons Demo.

Is it possible to select buttons in a certain div? Because in my code length of my list generated by findelements() is 7 but I would like it to be a 5 (only buttons from Group Radio Buttons should be selected).

I know div is the same for all buttons but is there any other (better) selector that can be used here?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

PATH = r"C:/Users/*****/PycharmProjects/chromedriver.exe"

s = Service(PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.get("http://demo.seleniumeasy.com/basic-radiobutton-demo.html")

#Single Radio Button Demo
button_radio_male = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,
                                        value="//label[normalize-space()='Male']//input[@name='optradio']")
button_radio_male.click()

button_get_checked_value = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="buttoncheck")
button_get_checked_value.click()


#Multiple Radio Button Demo
buttons = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@class='panel-body']//input[@type='radio']")
print(len(buttons))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can.
Instead of `"//div[@class='panel-body']//input[@type='radio']"` XPath locator you can use more precise locator

```py
"//div[contains(@class,'panel') and(contains(.,'Group Radio Buttons Demo'))]//div[@class='panel-body']//input[@type='radio']"
```

Actually it can even be shortened to this:

```py
"//div[contains(@class,'panel') and(contains(.,'Group'))]//div[@class='panel-body']//input[@type='radio']"
```

In the expression above we define the precise parent `div` element by it class name and text content of it child element.

Comment: Thank You for help. But what is the difference between first and second locator?

Comment: Looks like some mistake during pasting the code. I'll take a look at that tomorrow.

Comment: I have removed the redundant part in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `OR` in the Xpath to locate only those 5 elements. Below is the Xpath for the those radio buttons from the `Group Radio Buttons Demo`.

```
//input[@name='gender' or @name='ageGroup']
```

Comment: Thank You for help. But shouldn't this syntax be valid then?  `//input[@name='gender' or @name='ageGroup' or @name='optradio]` - I guess this should select all the radio buttons again, yes?

Comment: Yes, to select all the radio button you can use `//input[@name='gender' or @name='ageGroup' or @name='optradio']` and also this `//input[@type='radio']`.